# Orthogonal and positive basis function with support $[0,1]$

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, mathematical-modeling, machine-learning

I have a problem in my research where I have to use a linear combination of the form

$$f(u)=\sum_{i=1}^{M}\omega_{i}f_i(u)$$

I have some constraints on the basis functions $f_i$:

- $f_i(u)\geq0$
- to have support on $[0,1]$
- to be orthogonal ($\langle f_i, f_j \rangle = 0$ for $i\neq j$ and $\langle f_i, f_j \rangle = c$ for $i=j$).

I use at the moment Bernstein basis, but it is not orthogonal. I used the method from [Bellucci (2014)](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.2293.pdf) to make the Bernstein basis orthogonal, but I lose the positivity constraint...

Does anyone have an idea of such a basis? It doesn't have to be a polynomial basis.

Comment: What inner product are you using? Must the support be $[0,1]$ or can it be a proper subset of it?

Comment: I use the inner product $\langle f_i,f_j\rangle=\int_{0}^{1}f_i(u)f_j(u)du$. The support must be $[0,1]$.

Comment: If I suppose that the $f_i$ are continuous functions, then as $f_if_j\geq 0$, the fact that $\int_0^1f_i(t)f_j(t)dt=0$ imply that $f_if_j=0$. So what do you call the "support" of $f_i$ ?

Comment: I refer to $ f_i : [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb {R} $. I think I am looking for something that does not exist...

Comment: Could you use dirac-delta functions ?